# How to consume Multipart/form-data via Ruby Controllers?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, file-upload, controller, multipartform-data

I know I'm receiving a file with `Content-Type`: `multipart/form-data` in my controller and I understand the file was uploaded with something like this:

```
body[:uploaded_data] = Faraday::UploadIO.new(path, mime_type, hash[:filename])
```

and the content of the file I receive is like this

```
    -------------RubyMultipartPost
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="filename"

1_BsKbDTA9ZUVroeJ7asId4Q.png
-------------RubyMultipartPost
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="uploaded_data"; filename="RackMultipart20190205-12268-1eli4dv"
Content-Length: 34441
Content-Type: image/png
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary

‰PNG


 IHDR
awùé¨gP\ÆñÇèŒÎÌ_ý....
```

I'm trying to parse this so that I only get the content of the `png` file and save it as an actual `png` file.

I started by making a mock Rack env and parse it

```
env = Rack::MockRequest.env_for(
        '/',
        'CONTENT_TYPE' => request.headers['Content-Type'],
        'CONTENT_LENGTH' => request.body.length,
        'rack.input' => StringIO.new(request.body.read),
    )
    parsed_message = Rack::Multipart.parse_multipart(env)
```

and I know `parsed_message['uploaded_data']` has the second part but I still don't know how to properly parse out the 4 lines that include `Content-Disposition, Content-Length, Content-Type, Content-Transfer-Encoding` and get only the file content.

Any ideas are appreciated!

Comment: Can you please post your controller logs?

Comment: I actually realized my mistake. It does look like it's extra header on top of actual file data but that just happens when it's sent in the format of `ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile`. So, I just needed to use params[:uploaded_data].tempfile to get the file :)

Comment: In that case, please answer your own question and close it out :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually realized my mistake. It does look like it's extra header on top of actual file data but that just happens when it's sent in the format of ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile. So, I just needed to use params[:uploaded_data].tempfile to get the file :)